# Does completing a location stop vehicles spawning?

Tags: just-cause-2

The other day in JC2, I found a military base that keeps spawning fighter jets. Or at least, it was doing so initially when I discovered the base. Dozens of jets must have taken off while I softened the place up, tethered bad guys to the jets, tethered jets to the runway, etc. In due course I cleaned the place out, got the 'complete' banner, and moved on. Thing is when I went back there later, there weren't any more jets.

Would this base have kept spawning new jets if I hadn't completed it?  Or was there only a finite number of jets to begin with? I wanted to go back and try tying some vehicles to them!

(The base in question was Kem Sungai Sejuk at 17141, 12369).

Comment: Oooh... *runs off to tether a soldier to a jet*

Comment: I will make a mod to solve this!

Comment: That exact base and its missing jets annoyed me so much I did mod it:  
https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=576235628

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the planes will keep taking off while the location has not been completed, but once you complete it, they stop.

This is actually an issue with the game that can prevent 100% completion. There is at least one jet type that can *only* spawn in the "taking off" mode, so if you inadvertently complete all the locations where it can spawn without hijacking that jet type, you will never have another opportunity.

Comment: Actually, there are multiple vehicles that only appear once or twice in-game trough missions, but never again.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that jets keep departing as the base is still not taken over, but that's not the point here.

There are infinite jets no matter how many bases you take over (I know this cause I did took them all over), because jets will still spawn in the hangers, these hangers are usually located next to a runway so you can take off easily. Also they will still randomly spawn flying trough the air every once in a while (though they are very hard to catch).

Basically the only thing you are stopping from happening are the jets that take off every time you visit a base/airport. You will still be able to find lot's of them, don't worry.

Comment: i know there are a lot of airstrips with parked planes, where you can steal the plane, fly off to another location and when you come back, there will be a replacement plane. other ones, the planes keep taking off all the time. one air strip like this i cleaned out still generates planes, but they're no-guns civilian jets. but the one that was spawning fighters (with guns & rockets!) seems to NOT generate planes anymore. just wondering if there's any way to tell if a base will stop generating planes when you complete it.

Comment: the sheds are called "hangers" :)